# Easiest way to make long passages of glosses

Tags: spacing, automation, linguistics

What's the easiest way to do a long passage (like a full page or 2) of glosses? Would be great if I can convert directly from a spreadsheet like a CSV or something. If I can make a 2 column spreadsheet with glosses and output a nice looking doc, that would be great.

For those who aren't familiar with the notion of gloss, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you accept a solution based on LuaTeX?

Comment: @JairoADelRio Yes. I'm not using any other packages, the document would be a new one specifically for this.

Comment: Yes you can do this from a spreadsheet using ExPex. See [Doing an interlinear text](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/45520). Here's an example that you could work from.

Comment: @JairoADelRio Before you reinvent the wheel, there are quite a few packages specifically designed for linguistic glossing.

Comment: There's `expex` (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf), but it only does the typesetting. Lua can process .csv files so `expex` can format them

Comment: @AlanMunn Is there any way to make it work with overleaf?

Comment: It should work on Overleaf. It doesn't rely on any external tools, just packages that are part of any TeX distribution, including Overleaf.

Comment: But do you really need to automate this? Can't you just use ExPex without a spreadsheet?

Comment: @AlanMunn I tried copying your code from the answer to overleaf, and that's what it says: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a37Uh.png Is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @AlanMunn As for automation, I actually asked this question for a friend, so I can't answer right now, need to ask him first.

Comment: Well the error is pretty explicit: you need change the typesetting engine to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. This can be done by clicking on the Overleaf logo icon at the top left and changing the "Compiler".

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh, thank you, I didn't even know about the existence of that "menu" icon...

Comment: To be clear, the example mainly needs XeLaTeX because it's using Greek; most of the code doesn't depend on anything specific to XeLaTeX except for the font/language changing.  This could also be done in pdfLaTeX, but for linguistics work, it's usually simpler to use a unicode engine.